# How to add an empty array to object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties, variable-assignment

I'm having trouble adding my empty array into my object via the bracket notation method. I know how to get my empty array into the object via dot notation, but I just don't understand why the bracket notation isn't working for me.

**Update**: I understand my problem now; the context switch between dot notation & bracket notation blinded me & I completely failed to recall that in my 3rd block - animal[noises] (forgot the "") was trying to access the property value of the property noises, which I hadn't created yet in my object

Creating & adding properties to my object

```
var animal = {};
animal.username = "Peggy";
animal["tagline"] = "Hello";
```

Which will then create this:

```
animal {
      tagline: "Hello",
      username: "Peggy"
}
```

Why won't the following work when I'm  trying to add it into my object?

```
var noises = [];
animal[noises];
```

I'm getting this in my console (same as above):

```
animal {
      tagline: "Hello",
      username: "Peggy"
}
```

I was able to get my result this way:

```
animal.noises = [];
```

Which outputs this into my console:

```
animal {
  noises: [],
  tagline: "Hello",
  username: "Peggy"
}
```

But that still leaves me with the question: why doesn't this work via bracket notation?

Comment: `animal[noises];` means you are trying to access an attribute of `animal` with the name given by `noises`. You are not creating any attribute there.

Comment: I just updated the question. Take a look at the 3rd code block

Comment: @CliffordFajardo that doesn't change anything. You didn't expect `animal["Hello"];` to create a property called `tagline` with the value `Hello`, did you? Now why would you expect that `animal[[]]` (which is effectively your attempt) should create a property named `noises`? You clearly have no idea about the meaning of bracket notation, for what you should look it up in a beginner JavaScript tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
animal.noises = noises;
```

or

```
animal['noises'] = noises;
```

As when you are using `animal[noises];` it means when you are trying to read data from the object.

Comment: Thank you. I also failed to recall that with bracket notation I need "" around noises. Your response was succinct & clear.

Answer (score 1):

For `animal[noises]`,

- `animal` is the object
- and `noises` is the key/property of the object `animal`

And an array cannot be a key. If you want to put `noises` array in `animal` object you can do it as follows,

```
animal['noises'] = noises;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you have to try

```
animal['noises']=noises
```

Array `[]` notation is used to get property of an object that requires a quote around it. Array notations are commonly used to get identifiers of objects having special characters included.say,

```
   var animal={
      "@tiger":'carnivore' // you can't have @tiger without quote as identifier
   } 
  console.log(animal.@tiger) // it will give ERROR
  console.log(animal['@tiger']) // it will print out  'carnivore'
```

[this link has good explanation on array and dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) .

Comment: Thank you for the great, concise example!